# Getting the ID from exploding url

Tags: php

Currently I have the following code.

```
$file_id = 'https://skyvault.co/show/file?filename=6N2viQpwLKBIA6';
$parts = parse_url($file_id);
$path_parts = explode('/', $parts[path]);
$secret = $path_parts[3];
print $secret;
```

Above you can see that I am trying to explode by `/` and it's not returning the output I am looking for it's just returning `file` and I need it to return `6N2viQpwLKBIA6` so how could I get that ID?

Comment: why not use `$_GET['filename']` ?

Comment: @CodeGodie That's just a string that needs to be parsed.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Ritzy Hi. What does your variable `$path` hold? was that suppose to be a variable (since you missed the `$`)? Im just wondering what you were initially trying to do.

Comment: @CodeGodie it was suppose to be a variable it was just a bunch of mess trouble shoot code lol

Comment: lol gotcha. Yea coding can get messy sometimes. You almost had it though. I think you should stick with using `parse_url`. It is a more concise way of breaking up your URLs and like I said in my answer, you would just need to use the `query` index to get that info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible for you to do it quickly this way, if the URL is **always same** for all the items?

```
$URLComp = explode("show/file?filename=", $file_id);
$secret = $URLComp[1];
print $secret;
```

The main reason is, there could be cases of with or without `www`, then with or without `https`.

Comment: I tried this already and it didn't seem to work.. it didn't return any results at all when I tried and I just recoded using your code and still no luck..

Comment: @Ritzy It works here. Check: **http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4950c66a5dec11f6dd98f828d045e11ac207f4c6**

Comment: Yep! I got it working I was entering something wrong I guess, thank you so much for the extremely fast answer and sorry for the silly question!

Answer (score 4):

**[`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)** works but you need to specify the `query` index. Redo it like this:

```
$file_id = 'https://skyvault.co/show/file?filename=6N2viQpwLKBIA6';
$parts = parse_url($file_id);
$path_parts = explode('=', $parts['query']);
$secret = $path_parts[1];
print $secret;
```

Comment: Or even more prettier - without using explode: https://3v4l.org/8Y8Se - using **[`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str)**

Comment: @CodeBrauer that is true. `parse_url` would help in turning it into a one-liner. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you needs to use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-url.php) for any reason, you can use the `query` component instead of `path` as [suggested by @CodieGodie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35133039/3943162).

However, if you are handling with this url as a string, you can ignore `parse_url` and just work with it just like a string.

```
$file_id = 'https://skyvault.co/show/file?filename=6N2viQpwLKBIA6';
$parts = explode('/', $file_id);
$lastPart = end($parts);
$varParts = explode('=', $lastPart);//also explode('?', $lastPart) if you want "filename="
$secret = end($varParts);
print $secret;
```

Note: This code will work if your string always has the same format, this is: 'https://example.com/path/path/path?varName=varValue' with just 1 var in the end of the URL.